# Get ordinal number of child elements in multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an multidimensional array with child elements, and I want to get ordinal number from every parent and child element from array in format:

1.1.2 - First question, first child, first child of first child

2.1.2 - Second question, first child, Second child of first child

Here is the recursive function of array that I'm using

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parentId'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}

$tree = buildTree($questions);
```

Here is the example result of an array

```
Array
(
    [0] = Array
        (
            [id] = 156
            [question] = New Question
            [topicId] = 23
            [type] = 2
            [sortIndex] = 1
            [parentId] = 
            [parentOption] = 
            [children] =Array
                (
                    [0] = Array
                        (
                            [id] =&gt; 161
                            [question] = First Child to First Question
                            [topicId] = 23
                            [type] = 2
                            [sortIndex] = 2
                            [parentId] = 156
                            [parentOption] = Yes
                            [children] = Array
                                (
                                    [0] = Array
                                        (
                                            [id] = 163
                                            [question] = First Child to First Child
                                            [topicId] = 23
                                            [type] = 2
                                            [sortIndex] =; 5
                                            [parentId] = 161
                                            [parentOption] = Yes
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] = Array
                        (
                            [id] =&gt; 162
                            [question] = Second Child to first question
                            [topicId] =; 23
                            [type] = 2
                            [sortIndex] = 3
                            [parentId] = 156
                            [parentOption] = Yes
                            [children] = Array
                                (
                                    [0] = Array
                                        (
                                            [id] = 164
                                            [question] = First child to second child
                                            [topicId] = 23
                                            [type] = 2
                                            [sortIndex] = 4
                                            [parentId] = 162
                                            [parentOption] = Yes
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )



)
```

I'm using this function to get all items recursively.

```
function recursive($array, $level = 1){

    $i = 1;
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        //If $value is an array.
        if(is_array($value)){
            //We need to loop through it.
            recursive($value, $level + 1);
        } else{
            //It is not an array, so print it out.
            echo str_repeat("-", $level), $value, '<br>';
        }

    }
}
```

Any Ideas how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: You have a multidimensional array, not a recursive array.

Comment: How do you call `recursive()` and what is `$numbers`???

Comment: @AbraCadaver $numbers was part on something that I tested, I removed it.
I printing recursive method as print_r(recursive($tree)) for now when testing.